# Execution failed for task app processdebugresources failed to parse xml resource file android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error. what i can i do. please help i am new to android studio.
I have did my best to solve this but i am unable to solve this please help.
I am getting this error.
Error:Execution failed for task ':libraryMaskLayout:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to parse XML resource file 'D:\Android\FastChargerAdmob\libraryMaskLayout\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\res\values\values.xml'

[image]
Edit: I am updated the post and posted all gradle files i have in my project.
build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.TuAndroidPR.fast.Chargin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile project(':libraryMaskLayout')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'cn.fanrunqi:waveprogress:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.gradle(Module: libraryMaskLayout)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/annotations-12.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: There are 3 gradle files. for project, for app and for libraryMaskLayout which one should i post?

Comment: Post all 3 files

Comment: I have posted all gradle files here

Comment: Same problem here. Just updated to Android Studio 3.0 and Gradle Wrapper 4.1, updated a lot o things but somethig still wrong

Comment: Yes i had the same problem

Comment: Post your `values.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this issue when upgrading my `buildToolsVersion`.  In case anyone else has this issue, here's what I did to fix it:

I turned on `--stacktrace` for gradle, and found it was spitting out the following error after the "Failed to parse XML resource file" above:

```
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character
```

In `debug/res/values/values.xml`, I found this:

```
<enum name="DARKEN " value="2"/>
```

Per Android XML rules, a "element name" cannot have a space (`"DARKEN "`).

Searching for `"DARKEN "`, it lead me to a `<enum>` name in one of my XML files with `"DARKEN "` set to the XML element name.  I removed the trailing space, and the code compiled.

Answer (score 1):

lib build.gradle

dependencies {
...
 compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1'
}

Comment: Please explain your answer and format source code as such.

Comment: You need to delete or rename
<!--<enum name="DARKEN " value="2"/>-->

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by removing extra quotes manually from strings.xml...

In details: [How to solve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2048 out of bounds for length 2048 in AndroidStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77710158/how-to-solve-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-index-2048-out-of-bounds-for-length/77725358#77725358)